# How to show Stacked bar series Total value on top of the bar using jqplot

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas, jqplot

JqPlot provides point labels to show totals in a stacked chart i.e sum
on top of each series. What i want to show is the individual values of
each series within those series and finally the total sum of all the
series at the top of the sacked bar.
Is this possible with jqPlot?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. Easy workaround could be adding some sort of Total series (which will be just a sum of all existing series). Proper solution would be creating your own legend renderer (something similar to [Enhanced Legend Renderer](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-enhancedLegendRenderer-js.html))

Comment: Please Give an example for that

Comment: @user1422892 SO is not a place where people will do work for you - your question was about if that possible at all - yes that is possible. Just try something and when you will have exact issue - ask proper question.